# Django: drop-down-box

Tags: html, django, forms, web

My forms.py has this:

```
  SIZE_CHOICES = (
    ('s', 'Small'),
    ('m', 'Medium'),
    ('l', 'Large')
)

    class ChooseSize(forms.Form):
        size_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SIZE_CHOICES)
```

My product_page.html tries to implement this form:

```
<form method="POST" class="card-body">
          {% csrf_token %}
      <div>
            {{ form.size_choice }}
     </div>
</form>
```

For some reason size_choices doesn't show up on the web-page. What gives?

My views.py:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home/product-page.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an example maybe it helps you.

your model like this:

```
  SIZE_CHOICES = (
    ('s', 'Small'),
    ('m', 'Medium'),
    ('l', 'Large')
)
class YourModel(models.Model):
      size = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='',choices=SIZE_CHOICES,verbose_name="size")
```

**Form:**

```
class SizeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(SizeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
         model = YourModel
         fields = '__all__'
```

**Your View**

```
def your_view(request):
    form = SizeForm()
    return render_response('product_page.html',{'form': form})
```

**Template**

```
    <form method="POST" class="card-body">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <div>
                {% for x,y in form.fields.size_choice.choices %}
                {{x}} --> {{y}}
                {% endfor %}
         </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I'm still not seeing an output, I think because of what I have in my views.py. My view is controlled by the following class:

                     class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home/product-page.html"

Can I adapt the views.py for this class?